# SQL Server database being queried by python program errors out with same SQL code that runs fine directly on SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server, stored-procedures, view, pyodbc

I have read-only access to a SQL Server database. I want to use my Python program located on the same computer as the SQL Server database to query it using `SELECT`. The stored procedure attempt below is also a `SELECT` statement. I am using pyodbc module in Python.

I have made three attempts to get the data I want out of the database. All three attempts are nearly identical except where denoted below.

On my first attempt, I created a SQL statement that had a Common Table Expression, and four `SELECT` statements with several `INNER JOIN`'s and `LEFT OUTER JOIN`'s that are joined by `UNION ALL` statements. The query returns the correct result in a SQL Server query text editor but not from my Python program. In the Python program, it leaves out the part of the query obtained from the Common Table Expression portion. When running from within the SQL Server query text editor it does return the results with the common table expression part. However Python and pyodbc runs with no errors although it does not return anything from the Common Table Expression portion when the query is run from the Python program. After attempt 1, I decided to use an alternative to Common Table Expressions and did not try this in attempt 2 and 3.

My second attempt is to create a view in SQL Server directly on the SQL Server database and this view returns the exact same information that the Common Table Expression did earlier (Now I can substitute the view into my query in place of the common table expression). When I run this attempt, I get an error:

> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'dbo.VW_VIEW_NAME'. (208) (SQLExecDirectW)").

When I try to run this `dbo.VW_VIEW_NAME` on the SQL Server database using New Query it returns the resultset that I am seeking, but not when trying with Python and pyodbc. On SQL Server, I can browse to the view using the Object Explorer and looking in the Views folder. I can right-click the view, and create a select statement and execute it with results. I only have one database access account and it has read permission only. The SQL code calling the view in a query window in SQL Server runs just fine. All using the same SQL Server login credentials as the python program uses.

So SQL Server does not seem to be allowing the Python program and the pyodbc module to access the SQL Server database objects.

My third attempt is to move the entire SQL query from the Python program to a SQL Server stored procedure, and just execute the stored procedure from within my Python code (That way the SQL code is all being executed on the database, with no possibility of problems of it coming from outside of the database.) The database administrator granted me EXECUTE permission on my stored procedures. Once again I get an error similar to the error with the view:

> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.USP_MY_STORED_PROCEDURE'. (2812) (SQLExecDirectW)").

The SQL code calling the stored procedure in a query window in SQL Server runs just fine. All using the same SQL Server login credentials as the python program uses.

So whether pyodbc is reaching into SQL Server and accessing a view, or reaching into SQL Server and accessing a stored procedure, the result is the same: it does not say that it knows anything about these objects.

It seems that SQL Server might be blocking pyodbc and Python from accessing the view in one query attempt, and the stored procedure in another query attempt. Is there something that I need to correct in SQL Server to allow the view and the stored procedure to be accessible by outside programs?

In attempting to solve this problem, on separate troubleshooting steps, I did the following:
upgraded python version to the latest
upgraded Wing IDE to the latest
upgraded pyodbc to the latest
read the entire python DB 2.0 API
read the entire pyodbc documentation
Read many links on search engines

None of these attempts gave me the answer.

Is the problem a matter of SQL Server blocking access to view objects and stored procedure objects from outside access? Is there a setting in SQL Server that allows these things to get through that needs to be configured accordingly?

Here is the python code leading up to the cursor1.execute("...") statement

```
        conn1 = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
                                       +';SERVER='+server1+'; UID='+username1+'; PWD='+password1+';DATABASE='+database1)
        cursor1 = conn1.cursor()
        print('Before cursor 1 execute sql code ' + str(datetime.datetime.now()))
        cursor1.execute(r"""
```

My python version using is 3.8.2

pyodbc version using is 4.0.30

SQL Server version is SQL Server 2017

Operating system is Windows Server 2012

Thanks for helping me solve this problem.

Comment: You don't show enough code to indicate one way or the other... have you read the docs on [how to call a stored procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client-odbc-stored-procedures/calling-a-stored-procedure) from ODBC drivers like pyodbc?

Comment: It does not help to show code that builds strings that we cannot see. Show the actual connection string that is supplied for connection. At this point your errors suggest that you are not connecting to the database in which your view / procedure are created. This is not a "blocked" problem - the error is telling what it simply does not have an object with the name you tried to reference.

Answer (score 0):

To AlwaysLearning, I this response focuses on the database attempt that passes SQL code to the database and tries to make use of the view.

To SMor, I am going to paste the main code of the program up to the point of where the error is thrown. I kept most of the code of the program intact, deleting some comments and changing some usernamens and passwords and servers.

error received at line cursor1.execute(r"""

> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'dbo.VW_TB_TERM_SALE_ENTRIES'. (208) (SQLExecDirectW)")

Now for the python program up to the point of where the error is raised:

```
import LOG_INTO_HOTMAIL_SEND_ATTACH2
import datetime

import LOG_INTO_HOTMAIL_EMAIL_MESSAGE

import time

import CALCULATE_TERM_SALE_DISCOUNTED_PRICE

import pyodbc

# import pymssql

def ACCESS_DATABASE_WEBSTORE_QOH_DATA_4th_Attempt():

    UPC_CODE_QOH_Dictionary = {}
    UPC_CODE_QOH_Dictionary.clear()

    UPC_CODE_Cost_Dictionary = {}
    UPC_CODE_Cost_Dictionary.clear()

    UPC_CODE_Retail_Dictionary = {}
    UPC_CODE_Retail_Dictionary.clear()

    UPC_CODE_Compare_at_Price_Dictionary = {}
    UPC_CODE_Compare_at_Price_Dictionary.clear()

    # List_UPC_CODE_Add_Cost_and_Retail_At_End = []

    bln_Success = False

    while bln_Success is not (True):

        # ENCAPSULATE THE REST OF THE WHILE LOOP IN A TRY-EXCEPT BLOCK. SET bln_Success to True when 
        # the whole of the try block is successfully traversed.

        strErrorString = ''
        # server1 = "DESKTOP-24681012\\SQLEXPRESS_LWD"
        server1 = '123.456.78.90'
        database1 = 'db_name'
        # username1 = "DESKTOP-24681012\\lwdur"
        username1 = 'USERNAME_READ_ACCESS'
        password1 = 'Ab335**1'

        #try:

        conn1 = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
                                       +';SERVER='+server1+'; UID='+username1+'; PWD='+password1+';DATABASE='+database1)
        cursor1 = conn1.cursor()

        print('Before cursor 1 execute sql code ' + str(datetime.datetime.now()))

    -- THE BELOW cursor1 LINE IS WHERE THE ERROR IS GENERATED.
        cursor1.execute(r"""

                -- BELOW COMMENTS ARE THE 1ST ATTEMPT USING COMMON TABLE EXPRESSION.
                -- DATA TO BE RETRIEVED USING THE CTE WAS NOT RETRIEVED USING THIS
                -- PYTHON PROGRAM, THEREFORE I COMMENTED IT OUT AND ADDED THIS TO
                -- THE VIEW.

                                -- USE Celerant;
                                -- GO
                                -- WITH Term_Sale_Entries_CTE (STYLE_ID, ATTR1_ENTRY_ID, ATTR2_ENTRY_ID
                                -- , AMOUNT, ROUNDING, TYP, STORE_ID)
                                -- AS
                                -- (
                                -- SELECT STYLE_ID, ATTR1_ENTRY_ID, ATTR2_ENTRY_ID
                                -- , AMOUNT, ROUNDING, TYP, STORE_ID
                                -- FROM dbo.TB_TERM_SALE_ENTRIES
                                -- WHERE
                                -- GETDATE() BETWEEN [START_DATE]
                                -- AND END_DATE
                                -- AND (STORE_ID = 1
                                -- OR
                                -- STORE_ID = 99)
                                --ORDER BY STYLE_ID ASC
                                -- )
                                -- END OF COMMON TABLE EXPRESSION

-- BEGIN OF PORTION 1 OF UNION ALL SEGMENT
                                SELECT dbo.TB_STYLES.BRAND, dbo.TB_STYLES.STYLE ,
                                dbo.TB_STYLES.[DESCRIPTION], dbo.TB_STYLES.WEB_PRODUCT,
                                dbo.TB_SKU_BUCKETS.QOH, dbo.TB_SKU_BUCKETS.PRICE,
                                dbo.TB_SKU_LOOKUPS.[LOOKUP] AS UPC_CODE, TB_SKU_BUCKETS.AVG_COST,
                                dbo.VW_TB_TERM_SALE_ENTRIES.AMOUNT AS TERM_SALE_ENTRIES_AMOUNT,
                                dbo.VW_TB_TERM_SALE_ENTRIES.ROUNDING AS TERM_SALE_ENTRIES_ROUNDING,
                                dbo.VW_TB_TERM_SALE_ENTRIES.TYP AS TERM_SALE_ENTRIES_TYP,
                                dbo.VW_TB_TERM_SALE_ENTRIES.STYLE_ID
                                -- DELETE THIS ENTRY NEXT TO REVERT BACK TO ORIGINAL:
                                --INTO #TEMP_CURSOR_1_RESULTS
                                --,
                                -- dbo.TB_SKUS.SKU_OF3
                                FROM dbo.TB_STYLES
                                INNER JOIN dbo.TB_SKUS
                                ON dbo.TB_STYLES.STYLE_ID = dbo.TB_SKUS.STYLE_ID
                                INNER JOIN dbo.TB_SKU_BUCKETS
                                ON dbo.TB_SKUS.SKU_ID = dbo.TB_SKU_BUCKETS.SKU_ID
                                INNER JOIN dbo.TB_SKU_LOOKUPS
                                ON (
                                dbo.TB_SKUS.SKU_ID = dbo.TB_SKU_LOOKUPS.SKU_ID 
                                -- TB_SKU_LOOKUPS.SKU_ID CAN BE NULL BUT THIS IS OF NO CONSEQUENCE.
                                -- isnull(dbo.TB_SKUS.SKU_ID, -999)
                                -- =
                                -- isnull(dbo.TB_SKU_LOOKUPS.SKU_ID, -999)
                                )
                                LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.TB_ATTR1_ENTRIES
                                ON  (dbo.TB_SKUS.ATTR1_ENTRY_ID = dbo.TB_ATTR1_ENTRIES.ATTR1_ENTRY_ID) 
                                -- TB_ATTR1_ENTRIES.ATTR1_ENTRY_ID IS "NOT NULL". THEREFORE NO NEED TO CHECK FOR NULLS.
                                LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.TB_ATTR2_ENTRIES
                                ON ( dbo.TB_SKUS.ATTR2_ENTRY_ID = dbo.TB_ATTR2_ENTRIES.ATTR2_ENTRY_ID )
                                -- TB_ATTR2_ENTRIES.ATTR2_ENTRY_ID IS "NOT NULL". THEREFORE NO NEED TO CHECK FOR NULLS.

                                -- VW_TB_TERM_SALE_ENTRIES ATTR1_ENTRY_ID CAN BE NULL. ALSO ATTR2 ENTRY ID LIKEWISE.

                                LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                dbo.VW_TB_TERM_SALE_ENTRIES
                                ON dbo.VW_TB_TERM_SALE_ENTRIES.STYLE_ID = dbo.TB_STYLES.STYLE_ID 
                                -- STYLE_ID IS NEVER NULL IN TB_TERM_SALE_ENTRIES IN A SELECT STATEMENT WHERE STYLE_ID IS NULL
                                -- dbo.TB_STYLES.STYLE_ID CAN NOT BE NULL. THEREFORE IT IS OF NO CONSEQUENCE IF THE OTHER IS NULL.
                                AND (dbo.VW_TB_TERM_SALE_ENTRIES.ATTR1_ENTRY_ID = dbo.TB_SKUS.ATTR1_ENTRY_ID)                         
                                AND  dbo.VW_TB_TERM_SALE_ENTRIES.ATTR2_ENTRY_ID = dbo.TB_SKUS.ATTR2_ENTRY_ID
                                -- AND dbo.TB_SKU_BUCKETS.STORE_ID = dbo.VW_TB_TERM_SALE_ENTRIES.STORE_ID -- STORE_ID IS FREQUENTLY NULL

                                WHERE dbo.TB_STYLES.WEB_PRODUCT = 'Y' AND
                                dbo.TB_SKU_BUCKETS.STORE_ID = 1 AND
                                dbo.TB_SKUS.SKU_OF3 IS NULL
                                AND dbo.TB_SKUS.ATTR1_ENTRY_ID IS NOT NULL
                                AND dbo.TB_SKUS.ATTR2_ENTRY_ID IS NOT NULL

-- BEGINNING OF PORTION 2 OF UNION ALL
                                UNION ALL
                                SELECT dbo.TB_STYLES.BRAND, dbo.TB_STYLES.STYLE ,
                                dbo.TB_STYLES.[DESCRIPTION], dbo.TB_STYLES.WEB_PRODUCT,
                                dbo.TB_SKU_BUCKETS.QOH, dbo.TB_SKU_BUCKETS.PRICE,
                                dbo.TB_SKU_LOOKUPS.[LOOKUP] AS UPC_CODE, TB_SKU_BUCKETS.AVG_COST,
                                dbo.VW_TB_TERM_SALE_ENTRIES.AMOUNT AS TERM_SALE_ENTRIES_AMOUNT,
                                dbo.VW_TB_TERM_SALE_ENTRIES.ROUNDING AS TERM_SALE_ENTRIES_ROUNDING,
                                dbo.VW_TB_TERM_SALE_ENTRIES.TYP AS TERM_SALE_ENTRIES_TYP,
                                dbo.VW_TB_TERM_SALE_ENTRIES.STYLE_ID
                                -- DELETE THIS ENTRY NEXT TO REVERT BACK TO ORIGINAL:
                                --INTO #TEMP_CURSOR_1_RESULTS
                                --,
                                -- dbo.TB_SKUS.SKU_OF3
                                FROM dbo.TB_STYLES
                                INNER JOIN dbo.TB_SKUS
                                ON dbo.TB_STYLES.STYLE_ID = dbo.TB_SKUS.STYLE_ID
                                INNER JOIN dbo.TB_SKU_BUCKETS
                                ON dbo.TB_SKUS.SKU_ID = dbo.TB_SKU_BUCKETS.SKU_ID
                                INNER JOIN dbo.TB_SKU_LOOKUPS
                                ON (
                                dbo.TB_SKUS.SKU_ID = dbo.TB_SKU_LOOKUPS.SKU_ID
                                -- isnull(dbo.TB_SKUS.SKU_ID, -999)
                                -- =
                                -- isnull(dbo.TB_SKU_LOOKUPS.SKU_ID, -999)
                                )
                                LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.TB_ATTR1_ENTRIES
                                ON  (dbo.TB_SKUS.ATTR1_ENTRY_ID = dbo.TB_ATTR1_ENTRIES.ATTR1_ENTRY_ID)
                                LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.TB_ATTR2_ENTRIES
                                ON ( dbo.TB_SKUS.ATTR2_ENTRY_ID = dbo.TB_ATTR2_ENTRIES.ATTR2_ENTRY_ID )

                                LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                dbo.VW_TB_TERM_SALE_ENTRIES
                                ON dbo.VW_TB_TERM_SALE_ENTRIES.STYLE_ID = dbo.TB_STYLES.STYLE_ID -- STYLE_ID IS NEVER NULL IN TB_TERM_SALE_ENTRIES
                                -- AND (dbo.VW_TB_TERM_SALE_ENTRIES.ATTR1_ENTRY_ID = dbo.TB_SKUS.ATTR1_ENTRY_ID)                         
                                AND  dbo.VW_TB_TERM_SALE_ENTRIES.ATTR2_ENTRY_ID = dbo.TB_SKUS.ATTR2_ENTRY_ID
                                -- AND dbo.TB_SKU_BUCKETS.STORE_ID = dbo.VW_TB_TERM_SALE_ENTRIES.STORE_ID -- STORE_ID IS FREQUENTLY NULL

                                WHERE dbo.TB_STYLES.WEB_PRODUCT = 'Y' AND
                                dbo.TB_SKU_BUCKETS.STORE_ID = 1 AND
                                dbo.TB_SKUS.SKU_OF3 IS NULL
                                AND dbo.TB_SKUS.ATTR1_ENTRY_ID IS NULL
                                AND dbo.TB_SKUS.ATTR2_ENTRY_ID IS NOT NULL
-- BEGINNING OF 3RD UNION ALL SECTION
                                UNION ALL
                                SELECT dbo.TB_STYLES.BRAND, dbo.TB_STYLES.STYLE ,
                                dbo.TB_STYLES.[DESCRIPTION], dbo.TB_STYLES.WEB_PRODUCT,
                                dbo.TB_SKU_BUCKETS.QOH, dbo.TB_SKU_BUCKETS.PRICE,
                                dbo.TB_SKU_LOOKUPS.[LOOKUP] AS UPC_CODE, TB_SKU_BUCKETS.AVG_COST,
                                dbo.VW_TB_TERM_SALE_ENTRIES.AMOUNT AS TERM_SALE_ENTRIES_AMOUNT,
                                dbo.VW_TB_TERM_SALE_ENTRIES.ROUNDING AS TERM_SALE_ENTRIES_ROUNDING,
                                dbo.VW_TB_TERM_SALE_ENTRIES.TYP AS TERM_SALE_ENTRIES_TYP,
                                dbo.VW_TB_TERM_SALE_ENTRIES.STYLE_ID
                                -- DELETE THIS ENTRY NEXT TO REVERT BACK TO ORIGINAL:
                                --INTO #TEMP_CURSOR_1_RESULTS
                                --,
                                -- dbo.TB_SKUS.SKU_OF3
                                FROM dbo.TB_STYLES
                                INNER JOIN dbo.TB_SKUS
                                ON dbo.TB_STYLES.STYLE_ID = dbo.TB_SKUS.STYLE_ID
                                INNER JOIN dbo.TB_SKU_BUCKETS
                                ON dbo.TB_SKUS.SKU_ID = dbo.TB_SKU_BUCKETS.SKU_ID
                                INNER JOIN dbo.TB_SKU_LOOKUPS
                                ON (
                                dbo.TB_SKUS.SKU_ID = dbo.TB_SKU_LOOKUPS.SKU_ID
                                -- isnull(dbo.TB_SKUS.SKU_ID, -999)
                                -- =
                                -- isnull(dbo.TB_SKU_LOOKUPS.SKU_ID, -999)
                                )
                                LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.TB_ATTR1_ENTRIES
                                ON  (dbo.TB_SKUS.ATTR1_ENTRY_ID = dbo.TB_ATTR1_ENTRIES.ATTR1_ENTRY_ID)
                                LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.TB_ATTR2_ENTRIES
                                ON ( dbo.TB_SKUS.ATTR2_ENTRY_ID = dbo.TB_ATTR2_ENTRIES.ATTR2_ENTRY_ID )

                                LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                dbo.VW_TB_TERM_SALE_ENTRIES
                                ON dbo.VW_TB_TERM_SALE_ENTRIES.STYLE_ID = dbo.TB_STYLES.STYLE_ID -- STYLE_ID IS NEVER NULL IN TB_TERM_SALE_ENTRIES
                                AND (dbo.VW_TB_TERM_SALE_ENTRIES.ATTR1_ENTRY_ID = dbo.TB_SKUS.ATTR1_ENTRY_ID)                         
                                -- AND  dbo.VW_TB_TERM_SALE_ENTRIES.ATTR2_ENTRY_ID = dbo.TB_SKUS.ATTR2_ENTRY_ID
                                -- AND dbo.TB_SKU_BUCKETS.STORE_ID = dbo.VW_TB_TERM_SALE_ENTRIES.STORE_ID -- STORE_ID IS FREQUENTLY NULL

                                WHERE dbo.TB_STYLES.WEB_PRODUCT = 'Y' AND
                                dbo.TB_SKU_BUCKETS.STORE_ID = 1 AND
                                dbo.TB_SKUS.SKU_OF3 IS NULL
                                AND dbo.TB_SKUS.ATTR1_ENTRY_ID IS NOT NULL
                                AND dbo.TB_SKUS.ATTR2_ENTRY_ID IS NULL
-- BEGINNING OF 4TH UNION ALL SECTION
                                UNION ALL
                                SELECT dbo.TB_STYLES.BRAND, dbo.TB_STYLES.STYLE ,
                                dbo.TB_STYLES.[DESCRIPTION], dbo.TB_STYLES.WEB_PRODUCT,
                                dbo.TB_SKU_BUCKETS.QOH, dbo.TB_SKU_BUCKETS.PRICE,
                                dbo.TB_SKU_LOOKUPS.[LOOKUP] AS UPC_CODE, TB_SKU_BUCKETS.AVG_COST,
                                dbo.VW_TB_TERM_SALE_ENTRIES.AMOUNT AS TERM_SALE_ENTRIES_AMOUNT,
                                dbo.VW_TB_TERM_SALE_ENTRIES.ROUNDING AS TERM_SALE_ENTRIES_ROUNDING,
                                dbo.VW_TB_TERM_SALE_ENTRIES.TYP AS TERM_SALE_ENTRIES_TYP,
                                dbo.VW_TB_TERM_SALE_ENTRIES.STYLE_ID
                                -- DELETE THIS ENTRY NEXT TO REVERT BACK TO ORIGINAL:
                                --INTO #TEMP_CURSOR_1_RESULTS
                                --,
                                -- dbo.TB_SKUS.SKU_OF3
                                FROM dbo.TB_STYLES
                                INNER JOIN dbo.TB_SKUS
                                ON dbo.TB_STYLES.STYLE_ID = dbo.TB_SKUS.STYLE_ID
                                INNER JOIN dbo.TB_SKU_BUCKETS
                                ON dbo.TB_SKUS.SKU_ID = dbo.TB_SKU_BUCKETS.SKU_ID
                                INNER JOIN dbo.TB_SKU_LOOKUPS
                                ON (
                                dbo.TB_SKUS.SKU_ID = dbo.TB_SKU_LOOKUPS.SKU_ID
                                -- isnull(dbo.TB_SKUS.SKU_ID, -999)
                                -- =
                                -- isnull(dbo.TB_SKU_LOOKUPS.SKU_ID, -999)
                                )
                                LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.TB_ATTR1_ENTRIES
                                ON  (dbo.TB_SKUS.ATTR1_ENTRY_ID = dbo.TB_ATTR1_ENTRIES.ATTR1_ENTRY_ID)
                                LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.TB_ATTR2_ENTRIES
                                ON ( dbo.TB_SKUS.ATTR2_ENTRY_ID = dbo.TB_ATTR2_ENTRIES.ATTR2_ENTRY_ID )

                                LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                dbo.VW_TB_TERM_SALE_ENTRIES
                                ON dbo.VW_TB_TERM_SALE_ENTRIES.STYLE_ID = dbo.TB_STYLES.STYLE_ID -- STYLE_ID IS NEVER NULL IN TB_TERM_SALE_ENTRIES
                                -- AND (dbo.VW_TB_TERM_SALE_ENTRIES.ATTR1_ENTRY_ID = dbo.TB_SKUS.ATTR1_ENTRY_ID)                         
                                -- AND  dbo.VW_TB_TERM_SALE_ENTRIES.ATTR2_ENTRY_ID = dbo.TB_SKUS.ATTR2_ENTRY_ID
                                -- AND dbo.TB_SKU_BUCKETS.STORE_ID = dbo.VW_TB_TERM_SALE_ENTRIES.STORE_ID -- STORE_ID IS FREQUENTLY NULL

                                WHERE dbo.TB_STYLES.WEB_PRODUCT = 'Y' AND
                                dbo.TB_SKU_BUCKETS.STORE_ID = 1 AND
                                dbo.TB_SKUS.SKU_OF3 IS NULL
                                AND dbo.TB_SKUS.ATTR1_ENTRY_ID IS NULL
                                AND dbo.TB_SKUS.ATTR2_ENTRY_ID IS NULL


                                """)
```

Comment: I am going out of town for a few days, may not be able to respond immediately. Thanks to all for their suggestions.

Comment: I tested this SQL code on the SQL Server and it runs successfully.

Comment: Good evening

I worked on this problem some more tonight. I tried to use the pymssql python module but could not download it. I also tried using SQL version 13.1 instead of version 17. This errored out as my SQL Server version is 2017.

I found this webpage https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-pyodbc?view=sql-server-ver15 but it did not help. Should I go through the SQL code and make sure I have semicolons  and GO statements at the right places?